# How can I nest a listviews with recycleviews?

Tags: android, listview, user-interface, android-recyclerview

[image]

Trying to do something like this, I attempted with a RecycleView nested with a listview. If it`s not possible, can you suggest me a more suitable UI element to get to the design?

Comment: You can use Expandable List View https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView

Comment: Try this out https://android.jlelse.eu/get-expandable-recyclerview-in-a-simple-way-8946046b4573

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is best to use ViewTypes for this problem. Multiple listviews wil result in scrolling issues. Define a viewtype for different views.

Or Expandable ListView could be an option as well.

Comment: This should be comment.